В input времени минуты сделать не редактируемыми
В проекте есть input времени, в котором можно вводить часы и минуты (00:00).
Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы можно было вводить только часы (1:00, 5:00 итд), а минуты остаются :00.
Я сделала через label (:00) и в целом он рабочий. НО в другой части проекта из бека приходят старые данные с минутами (0:15, 1:30) и нужно сделать так, чтобы эти минуты отображались. Это один тот же компонент.
Как можно сделать еще?

Если вас интнрнсует теория: то разбить время на часы и минуты и часы положить в инпут, а минуты в лейбл. Если практическая часть, нужен ваш код

Вам правильно ответили.
Разбиваете время в примере если пришла строка "10:30"
// time = "10:30"
let timeArr = time.split(":")
// Выводи отдельно часы / отдельно минуты и передаем их куда необходимо
console.log( timeArr[0], timeArr[1] )

